# How can I join the one column into partition of row?

Tags: asp.net

I designed my Gridview

```
<td>
   <asp:GridView EnableViewState="false" ID="GridView1" runat="server" BackColor="silver"
                 BorderColor="silver" BorderStyle="None" GridLines="Both" CellPadding="3" 
                 CellSpacing="3" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%">
      <Columns>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Agentname" HeaderText="Agent Name" 
               ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" ItemStyle-Width="8%" 
               ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center"
               HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle">
              <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle"></HeaderStyle>
              <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="8%"></ItemStyle>
          </asp:BoundField>
       </Columns>
       <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="center" Font-Size="Small" BackColor="white" />
       <HeaderStyle BackColor="#35b0c9" ForeColor="white" Font-Size="small" HorizontalAlign="center" />
    </asp:GridView>
</td>
```

Please help me how can I get the gridview like this

```
                  SMS                            Email
```

AGentname  SMS Recivecd Pending Replied    REceived Pending Replied

Comment: Can you improve the formatting please? Please remove most of the indent from your ASP code so that it's visible without scrolling and indented neatly, and then try and make your example clearer: you want two levels of column headers with the second level grouped by the top level?

Answer (score 0):

Hey use `Template column`

```
  <asp:GridView ID="gvInternalJobPostingDetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <HeaderStyle BackColor="#FFF7EE" Font-Size="10pt" ForeColor="#D83535" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SMS">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblSrno" runat="server" Text='<%# ((IJP)Container.DataItem).SMS'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">
                        <ItemTemplate>

                                <asp:Label ID="lblgvCode" runat="server" Text='<%# ((IJP)Container.DataItem).Email %>'></asp:Label>



                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Hope it help you